# Facing issues on receiving SMS

Tags: twitter, twilio

I add my twilio verified number to twitter account and twitter send activation code, but in my twilio console there is no message from twitter.
Can anyone please guide me!!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio numbers cannot receive SMS from short codes, is Twitter sending via a Shortcode?

[Can Twilio numbers receive SMS from a short code?](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223181668-Can-Twilio-numbers-receive-SMS-from-a-short-code-)